# Want to create a program to scale a linked list by a certain factor

Tags: python

I want to write a function where you input a linked list and a factor, and the function returns a new linked list scaled by that factor. For example:

```
scale(linkify([1, 2, 3]), 2)
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> None
```

First, I made a function that, when you input a list of items, converts into a linked list. This is it here:

```
def linkify(item: list[int]) -> Optional[Node]:
    """Return a Linked List of Nodes with same values and same order as input list."""
    if len(item) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(item) == 1:
        return Node(item[0], None)
    else:
        return Node(item[0], linkify(item[1:]))
```

Now, I'm trying to write the function in order to scale that list.

Here is what I have now for the function:

```
def scale(head: Optional[Node], factor: int) -> Optional[Node]:
    """Returns new linked list of nodes where each value in original list is scaled by scaling factor."""
    if head is None:
        return None
    else:
        return Node(head.data * factor, scale(head.next, factor))
```

However, when I try to test this, I get an error saying exercises.ex11.linked_list.Node object at 0x0000013392C97C10>, and I'm not entirely sure what this means. Can anyone tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Also, I have to create the function recursively, and can't use any other functions outside the ones I've created.

Here is the test case I created as well:

```
def test_scale_factor() -> None:
    linked_list: list[int] = [1, 2, 3]
    linked_list_2: list[int] = [2, 4, 6]
    assert is_equal(scale(linkify(linked_list), 2), linkify(linked_list_2))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you forgot to implement `__repr__` or `__str__` in your `Node` class.

Comment: I do have a __str__ method in my Node class!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a proper solution for your case?
I always try to avoid using recursions.
Sure you also can add some checks on the function inputs.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def linkify(self, nodes):
        if len(nodes) == 0:
            return
        self.head = node = Node()
        for i in nodes:
            node.next = Node(i)
            node = node.next
        self.head= self.head.next
        
    def is_equal(self, other_llist):
        node1 = self.head
        node2 = other_llist.head
        while node1 and node2:
            if node1.data != node2.data:
                return False
            node1 = node1.next
            node2 = node2.next
        if node1 or node2:
            return False
        return True
        
    def scale(self, factor):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            node.data *= factor
            node = node.next

llist1 = Linkedlist()
llist1.linkify([1, 2, 3])
llist1.scale(2)

llist2 = Linkedlist()
llist2.linkify([2, 4, 6])

print(llist1.is_equal(llist2))
```